# Linking to [tag] searches doesn't work unless the brackets are URL encoded

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, hyperlinks, url-encoding

If you want to link to a tag search such as the following:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xml]+[php]+parse
```

It won't create a link unless the square brackets are URL encoded.  That is, this doesn't work:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xml]+[php]+parse

But this does:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D+%5Bphp%5D+parse

Would it be feasible to automatically URL encode these links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the solution is to use a [link created with Ctrl-L or the link button in the toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xml]+[php]+parse).

This confused me because the preview below doesn't show a link.

**Source:**

```
So apparently the solution is to use a [link created with Ctrl-L or the link button in the toolbar][1].

This confused me because the preview below doesn't show a link.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xml]+[php]+parse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the other link formats [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xml]+[php]+parse); there is a limit to what the "naked" (most naive) form can support.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry Jeff, (or anyone else) can you post the syntax you used for that link? I don't have edit privs to peek.  I did try a few different formats - IIRC html didn't work, and neither did the WMD linkify button.

Comment: @therefromhere: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fc916bce-b4d6-4a5b-8d78-e19c114d3154/view-source
(and then read the link he posted for more ways of linking)

Comment: @Jeff - I noticed that using the syntax you suggest, the link doesn't appear in the preview (on Firefox 3.6.3 on Windows 7) - is this a known bug?  (see my answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44272/linking-to-tag-searches-doesnt-work-unless-the-brackets-are-url-encoded/48549#48549 )

Comment: @there there are about 5 different link syntaxes; did you try them all? The client side JavaScript Markdown renderer may have subtle deviations from the C# server side Markdown renderer.

Comment: the link format created by Ctrl-L was the one I was referring to, I haven't tried the others.